# How to save and work with data using pointers and list in C

Tags: c

My programs idea is to insert data like this to the program (see below), and save it to a list, so I can keep using it.

```
Room;Epoch-time;Day;Month;Year;Hour;Minute;Amount
Dining;1577833140;01;01;2020;01;59;0
Dining;1577833200;01;01;2020;02;00;0
...
Bedroom;1569905580;01;10;2019;07;53;0
Bedroom;1569906540;01;10;2019;08;09;2
```

```
Node* readFile(Node *pStart, char *fileName) {
    char memory[20], tempName[20];
    FILE *file;
    int i=0;

    file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to read file.\n");
    }

    else {
        while (fgets(memory, sizeof(memory), file) != NULL) {
            sscanf(memory, "%s", tempName);
            if (sscanf(memory, "%s", tempName) == '\0') {
                pStart == AddList(pStart, tempName);
                break;
            }

            pStart = AddList(pStart, tempName);
            i++;
        }

        printf("file '%s' has been read, '%d' rows.\n", fileName, i);
        printf("\n");
        fclose(file);
    }

    return pStart;
}
```

The problem is, how can I work with the data, so I could compile the data to following form to a txt file:

```
Room: Bedroom
Date Time Amount
1.9.2019 03:00 0
1.9.2019 03:01 0
...
```

How can I save the date to its corresponding variable? My current code for saving the file is, but it does not work:

```
NodeResult *SaveResult(NodeResult *pStartResult, char *name) {
    FILE *file;
    NodeResult *ptr = pStartResult;
    file = fopen(name, "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Filed to write to the file.\n");
    }

    else {
        fprintf(Date Time Amount\n");
        while (ptr != NULL) {
            fprintf(%02d%02d%02d\n", ptr->date, ptr->Time, ptr->Amount);
            ptr = ptr->pNextResult;
        }

        printf("File saved\n");
        printf("\n");
        fclose(file);
    }

    return pStartResult;
}
```

Comment: Explain "does not work". Does it compile? Does it run? Does it do anything that it should not? (Do not answer in a comment: [edit] your question and add all missing useful information.)

Comment: @usr2564301: As far as I understand it, all the OP is asking for is for a means to convert epoch time to calendar data and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert [Epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) to a [`struct tm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm) representing

- [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) using the function [`gmtime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/gmtime).
- local time using the function [`localtime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime).

Afterwards, you can use `fprintf` with the individual members of the `struct tm` to accomplish what you want.

Assuming that you make `ptr->epoch_time` of type `time_t`containing the Epoch time, you can change your `while` loop to the following:

```
while (ptr != NULL) {
    struct tm *p = localtime( &ptr->epoch_time );
    assert( p != NULL );
    fprintf(
        file,
        "%d.%d.%d %02d:%02d %d\n",
        p->tm_mday, p->tm_mon, p->tm_year,
        p->tm_hour, p->tim_min,
        ptr->Amount
    );
    ptr = ptr->pNextResult;
}
```

However, as far as I can tell, your parsing of the input is also not working. Instead of using `sscanf`, I suggest you consider using [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to split the input fields using `';'` as the deliminator character.